# Discord.py how can I test if a member has certain role in a dictionary of roles?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
AdminRoles = ["Moderation","Administration","Emperor"]
@client.command()
async def Commands(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    if AdminRoles in member.roles:
        ShowCommand = discord.Embed(
            title = "Moderation Commands",
            description = "All commands",
            colour = discord.Colour.red()
        )
        await ctx.send(embed = ShowCommand)
    else:
        ShowCommand = discord.Embed(
            title = "Member Commands",
            description = "All commands",
            colour = discord.Colour.red()
        )
        await ctx.send(embed = ShowCommand)
```

I do I fix the code above because when I type in the command it keeps displaying the normal player command and it is suppose to display the Mod commands.

Comment: Should a moderator have all these `AdminRoles` roles?

Comment: @Nurqm, I'm trying to make it that if a person has any one of the roles in AdminRoles then run the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you did `if AdminRoles in member.roles:`. This means that if member has all of the `AdminRoles`. So you can change your code like this:

```py
AdminRoles = ["Moderation","Administration","Emperor"]
@client.command()
async def Commands(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    for role in member.roles:
        if role.name in AdminRoles:
            ShowCommand = discord.Embed(
                title = "Moderation Commands",
                description = "All commands",
                colour = discord.Colour.red()
            )
            await ctx.send(embed = ShowCommand)
            return
    ShowCommand = discord.Embed(
        title = "Member Commands",
        description = "All commands",
        colour = discord.Colour.red()
    )
    await ctx.send(embed = ShowCommand)
```

In this code, if member has any of the `AdminRoles`, Moderation Commands will send.

Comment: It did not work, it displays Member Command instead of Mod command for me. Do I need to include the role name or the role id?

Comment: Instance of str has no 'name' member. It did not work

Comment: Are you sure that you use the same code that I wrote?

Comment: Nevermind, I thought you just modified role to role.name. Thank you it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking if the list `AdminRoles` is inside member.roles, the **whole** list as:

```
if ["a","b","m"] in members.roles:
```

but you want that one of the items in AdminRoles is inside members.role, so you need something like:

```
test = [e for e in AdminRoles if e in members.roles]
if len(test) > 0:
    doTheRightModeratorThing()
else:
    doTheRightCommonerThing()
```

(this last check if at least one of the roles in the adminRoles is in the member.roles)

Comment: It did not work, it displays Member Command instead of Mod command for me. Do I need to include the role name or the role id?

Comment: My fault, the if condition was greater than 0, not greater than 1! Sorry! I've correct it in the code snippet in the answer, now it would work.

Comment: It did not work, it still displays the member command.